# How to prove limit towards infinity of a matrix to its power exist

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is an $n × n$ matrix that is diagonalizable (so it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors). What must be true for the limit $A^k$ to exist as $k → ∞$?

Comment: Well, if $A = PDP^{-1}$, then $A^k = P D^k P^{-1}$, so just think about what $D^k$ looks like.

Comment: IOW , $|\lambda_i| \leq 1$ for $i=1,2,,,n$

Comment: @gary that's necessary but not quite sufficient; for instance $A = -I$ is problematic.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Outside of that, alternating terms, what other issues are there? Aren't they essentially the same issues re convergence of a sequence $a_k^n$?

Comment: Of course there are no other issues (as long as we take $a_n \in \Bbb C$), but it still bears mentioning.